# The descriptive statistic, python

Tags: python, pandas

I learned the descriptive statistic of python. And there I want to create a summary table include mean and standard deviation and so on. But I can't Orderly arrangement the content of table.

**This is my Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table ('OECDpop.csv' , sep=' ')

summary = df.describe()

print(summary)
```

**This is my Output:**

```
Country,DAGEGR,Age groups,DSEX,DSTATUS,Status             of  \

count                 328                        328            328   

unique                 29                          5            274   

top                United              ages,1,90,All  ages,1,90,All   

freq                   22                        273             55   

            population,Year,MALE,FEMALE  

count                                55  

unique                               55  

top     population,2002,5005508,5264218  

freq                                  1
```

**This is my expect table**

```
    Received    Eligible    Rate

count   1.220000e+02    1.220000e+02    122.000000

mean    1.507967e+05    1.892901e+05    78.434426

std 3.740830e+05    4.661560e+05    9.274971

min 5.800000e+02    8.810000e+02    46.400000

25% 1.914425e+04    2.593575e+04    72.625000

50% 6.866200e+04    9.038250e+04    79.550000

75% 1.871065e+05    2.532840e+05    86.700000

max 3.317755e+06    4.061389e+06    90.900000
```

Answer (score 0):

just try with:

```
print(df.describe())
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have one line of data only string this so instead of number stats you are getting word stats.